# does bash script set variables by reference?

Tags: bash, alias

I'm trying to get some new aliases set and came across a strange one.

```
alias l="ls"
alias ls="ls -alGh"
```

I'd like to shorten the default file list to `L` and set an *all info* one to the default, `LS`, but all I ever get is:

```
~ Desktop $ unalias ls
~ Desktop $ unalias l
~ Desktop $ source ~/.bash_aliases
~ Desktop $ l
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   3 astagl  staff   .
drwxr-xr-x  34 astagl  staff   ..
-rw-r--r--   1 astagl  staff   2015-06-07_10.50.54.inline editor.html
~ Desktop $ ls
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   3 astagl  staff   .
drwxr-xr-x  34 astagl  staff   ..
-rw-r--r--   1 astagl  staff   2015-06-07_10.50.54.inline editor.html
~ Desktop $
```

Directory listing above: I'm clearing out the aliases first, just to start over and source my alias script which includes the first listed code block. Is there some kind of weird variable *referencing* going on here?

---

### Solution

using the backsplashes seems to do the trick:

```
alias l="\ls -a"
alias ls="\ls -al"
```

Comment: After 2 `unalias` commands if you do `type l` what output do you get?

Comment: `-bash: l: command not found`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When expanding an alias, other aliases may be invoked recursively. To avoid that you need to escape the commands in the aliases using a backslash:

```
alias l="\ls"
alias ls="\ls -alGh"
```